# Vendoring in Go 1.6

Tags: go, vendor

I’ve read as many docs and StackOverflow articles as I can find, yet I am having no luck importing using the new vendor feature in Go 1.6.

Here's a sample project I put together with [Goji](https://github.com/zenazn/goji) to test. The directory structure is as such:

```
.
└── src
    ├── main.go
    └── vendor
        └── github.com
            └── zenazn
                └── goji
                    ├── LICENSE
                    ├── README.md
                    ├── bind
                    ├── default.go
                    ├── example
                    ├── goji.go
                    ├── graceful
                    ├── serve.go
                    ├── serve_appengine.go
                    └── web
```

And `main.go`, the sole file in the project, is as such:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

func hello(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", c.URLParams["name"])
}

func main() {
    goji.Get("/hello/:name", hello)
    goji.Serve()
}
```

My environment variables are as such:

```
export GOPATH=~/.go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin:$GOBIN
```

I’ve tried the most simple build commands, with no luck:

```
go run ./src/main.go
go build ./src/main.go
```

I’ve also attempted to build with:

```
$GOPATH=`pwd`
```

...to no avail. Am I totally missing something? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The whole branch under src should be in a subdirectory, no?  Can you try making a directory "foo" and move `main.go` and `vender` under it.

Comment: Could you please post what exact commands you tried and what error messages you got?

Comment: @kostya Edited to add build commands.

Comment: @sberry No luck. But is vendoring only for libraries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you to read https://golang.org/doc/code.html. It requires a day or two to digest but after you understand how go tools work with the source code and GOPATH it is really easy to use them.

Back to your question. To build a simple go program you need to:

- create directory under $GOPATH/src, e.g. `mkdir $GOPATH/src/myprogram`
- put all the source code (including vendor directory) there: `$GOPATH/src/myprogram/main.go`, `$GOPATH/src/myprogram/vendor`.
- run `go install myprogram` to build your application and put the resulting `myprogram` binary to `$GOPATH/bin/myprogram`

Comment: Thank you so much @kostya; you solved it for me. There were two things I needed to do: properly set `$GOPATH`, and move the project to a subdirectory under `./src`.

Comment: moving the project to `src/` did it for me