# How to limit / stop golangs go tool from going to the internet

Tags: go

We recently brought Golang into the company that I work in for general use, but we hit a snag in the roll out because Go can use the `go get` command to get packages from the internet. Typically when we roll out Java and Python we are able to limit where the developer can pull packages from by pointing them to our internal artifactory.

So with Python we can change where they pull from by altering the pip command to pull from our internal artifactory, and with Java we can alter their settings.xml and pom.xml to point to our internal packages.

I know that during development you can fetch and pull in dependencies into your local then compile them into a standalone binary. What i am looking for is some mechanism that stops people from going out and pulling from the open internet.

Does something like this exist in Go? Can I stop people from going to the internet and `go get` 'ing packages?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can always [git clone your private repositories](https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https) instead of using `go get`, and make that the expected way to do things on your team.

Comment: Yes. Disconnect the workstations/laptops/servers. If your company allows git clone whats wrong with go get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I use vendor in Go 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237036/how-should-i-use-vendor-in-go-1-6)

Comment: `go get`'s entire purpose is to connect to the internet to get dependencies. If you don't want it to connect to the internet, don't use it. The other `go` commands do not require internet access.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your definition of "roll out", but typically there are three stages:

1. Development - at this point you can't prevent arbitrary `go get` calls, apart from putting the development machines behind restrictive proxies or similar technical measures.
2. Deployment - since Go programs can (should) be deployed as single binaries, `go get` is not used at all during deployment.
3. Building deployment artefacts - this is probably your issue:

The usual approach is not to fetch dependencies when *building* Go programs. Instead, dependencies are fetched during *development*, and made part of the source tree using [vendoring](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/), for example by using the [`dep`](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/introduction.html) tool.

At this point, the build step no longer needs to fetch any dependencies. The choice of which dependencies are allowed now becomes part of the rest of your process, such as code reviews.

Comment: Ok, our packaging teams biggest issue is with the fact that in development they can go out to the internet and download any package then compile it into a single binary and we would not know what was in that binary potentially(company is over 10000, lots of people to manage)

Comment: @bR3nD4n You can run `go list -f '{{ .Deps }}' binary` to see the complete list of imported packages in that binary. You can also point it at a directory to see the complete list of imported packages in a source tree.

Answer (score 0):

If *you* want to prohibit internet use of golang tools on *your* computer, you can perform module dependency downloads once-and-for-ever and then deny write permissions to the recursive directories under %GOPATH% (and %GOROOT%). (find it with `go env GOPATH`)

It is not as easy to stop *other* users using on-the-fly downloaded modules, as this could be circumvented by using vendor/source packages or by manually setting %GOPATH%.

Answer (score 0):

The way you say it seems ambiguous to me... do you want *users* to never be able to get modules or do you want this for say, automated builds?

I would say instead of wholesale prevention of module downloading, there's two important techniques (which can be combined)

**Vendoring**

If you just want to prevent a specific build stage (like say a Docker build) from doing this, then make your root module have a `vendor` folder. A [vendor folder works similar to `node_modules` et al](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring), and this vendor folder is supposed to then have a folder structure of all the dependencies.

By default in newer Go versions (GO111MODULE=auto), the existence of a vendor folder prevents fetching dependencies.

If you want, you can commit the vendor folder to git and then you ensure your CI builds are stable and never try to fetch modules.

**GOPRIVATE for specific dependencies**

In addition to vendoring, if you just want to have a "private set of modules" or you want your system to not hit the public registry, you have two additional options: the GOPRIVATE and GOPROXY env vars.

GOPRIVATE says "don't check the public module cache for these module prefixes"
e.g. you can set env var `GOPRIVATE=mycompany.com/prefix,otherthing.com/prefix`

Anything not matched by GOPRIVATE still goes to the public go proxy.

You can in theory set `GOPRIVATE=*` though I find this makes the development experience annoying... it might be useful in automated builds&CI.

In addition, you can use GOPROXY to completely prevent all "public" calls out to get modules, [alternately set up your own caching proxy that also prevents outgoing calls on some patterns](https://goproxy.io/docs/GOPRIVATE-env.html)

I think this is the closest to your artifactory example.

I will mention that Go prefers git-based repositories, so without running your own "artifact proxy" you can do a budget version of having private modules (presuming github org with private repositories) by doing e.g. `GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany` and not needing an artifact server at all.