# cannot find vendor directory under golang project

Tags: go, gopath, govendor

My golang version is go1.10.2 linux/amd64. I can build and run my go project(under gopath/src) without any problem but I cannot see vendor directory under my project folder. I would like to know if the vendor folder is a hidden directory? What are the possible reasons the vendor folder is not generated?

Comment: Why would you expect a vendor directory?

Comment: "What are the possible reasons the vendor folder is not generated?" --- it's not done automatically. If you haven't done it explicitly - it's not created and used. Check https://github.com/golang/dep

Comment: Thank you! Will look into the link provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vendor directory is used as an alternative to `GOPATH` when resolving dependencies. A dependency is first looked up in `/vendor` then in `GOPATH` then in `GOROOT`.

If you `go get` all your dependencies they'll be in `GOPATH/src` instead of `/vendor`.

To start adding project specific dependencies to vendor dir you need to use a dependency manager such as `glide` or `dep` or manually copy everything to `/vendor`.

This SO answer goes into more detail on using vendor dir in Go - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238226/1589165