# Golang 1.8 glide vendor folder ignoring

Tags: go, vendor, glide-golang, gopath, govendor

I'm working in Go version 1.8, Glide for package dependency and my project structure is

```
/Users/myName/go
    bin/
    pkg/
    src/
        main.go
        vendor/
            github.com/
            gaoling.org/
```

all my packages are installed in vendor folder after doing `glide install`, when I do `go build` it is giving following error

```
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" in any of:
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOROOT)
/Users/myName/go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOPATH)
```

and `go env` is

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/myName/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/st/28pcgmmj1sb84ch1n_76g_k00000gn/T/go-build454728554=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: I think this an issue related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999046/vendoring-in-go-1-6

Comment: thanks @EddyHernandez, is it possible to put only `GitHub`, `golang`, `gopkg` packages in `vendor` and rest of the packages in under app/src folder

Comment: I used vendor directory inside my projects  for example github.com/user/myapp/vendor and not in the root of src.

Comment: oh thanks @EddyHernandez, I'm new to GO,

Answer (score 0):

The glide works the old way, So you need to move your code to the folder `/Users/myName/go/src/github.com/projectName` and run glide. Your main.go and vendor file should come under your projectName folder.